# How do I update tkinter canvas widgets dynamically?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, simulation

I am writing a program to simulate a railroad signal that will eventually run on a Raspberry Pi receiving analog signals through an ADC to drive the different signal colors.

I am very bad at GUI programming so my question is, how do I write a function to change the color of each "LED" that I can eventually call each time a high voltage is detected? For now, I just want to have a function, set_top_signal("Green"), that can be called to update the graphic.

I want to then write a function to flash the signal  on and off every half of second.
flash_top_signal("Green")

[Current GUI Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89KxW.png)

```
import tkinter as tk

class WaysideSimulator(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        # self.pack()
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):

        self.Searchlight_Button = tk.Button(self, text="Start Simulation", command=self.start_simulation())
        # self.Searchlight_Button.pack(side="bottom")
        self.Searchlight_Button.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.End_Simulation_Button = tk.Button(self, text="End Simlation", fg="red", command=self.master.destroy)
        # self.End_Simulation_Button.pack(side="bottom")
        self.End_Simulation_Button.grid(row=1, column=0)

        # Draw the Signal Rectangle
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=500, height=500, bg="white")
        # self.rectangle.pack()
        self.canvas.grid()

        # Draw the Searchlight Signal Heads
        self.signal_pole = self.canvas.create_rectangle(245, 20, 255, 500, fill="grey")

        self.top_signal_head = self.canvas.create_oval(200, 10, 300, 110, fill="black")
        self.middle_signal_head = self.canvas.create_oval(200, 160, 300, 260, fill="black")
        self.bottom_signal_head = self.canvas.create_oval(200, 310, 300, 410, fill="black")

        self.top_signal_light = self.canvas.create_oval(240, 50, 260, 70, fill="red")
        self.middle_signal_light = self.canvas.create_oval(240, 200, 260, 220, fill="yellow")
        self.bottom_signal_light = self.canvas.create_oval(240, 350, 260, 370, fill="green")

    def set_top_signal_color(self, color):
        self.canvas.delete(self.top_signal_light)
        self.canvas.delete(self.middle_signal_light)
        self.canvas.delete(self.bottom_signal_light)

        """
        Signal Color Code Chart:
        0 = Black(Off)
        1 = Red
        2 = Yellow
        3 = Green
        """
        if color == "Off":
            self.top_signal_light = self.canvas.create_oval(240, 50, 260, 70, fill="black")
        elif color == "Red":
            self.top_signal_light = self.canvas.create_oval(240, 50, 260, 70, fill="red")
        elif color == "Yellow":
            self.top_signal_light = self.canvas.create_oval(240, 50, 260, 70, fill="yellow")
        elif color == "Green":
            self.top_signal_light = self.canvas.create_oval(240, 50, 260, 70, fill="green")

    def start_simulation(self):
        print("Searchlight Simulation Started")


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Searchlight Simulator")
    root.geometry("500x525")
    root.resizable(0, 0)
    s1 = WaysideSimulator(master=root)
    s1.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What did you try so far, and where did it fail?

Comment: I tried writing a function set_top_signal(self) that used the IntVar signal_color by changing its value to different values but it didnt work.

Comment: What exactly didn't work? Please add an example. To learn more on how to ask a question in Stack Overflow, please visit: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Itamar, I have updated my post to include that function set_top_signal to the code that is currently not working per your request.

Comment: Do you actually want to call `flash_top_light("green")` in `start_simulation()`?

Answer (score 0):

I recently asked a similar question about rotating through images of dice to simulate a pair of dice rolling.  Perhaps if all you need to do is "rotate" to a new "signal" image then you could cannibalize what you need from the working code I posted at this link (please credit acw1668 without whose help I would not have arrived at a working version!):

[Tkinter, python 3.8.1, win10Pro, How can I change a label image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60312754/tkinter-python-3-8-1-win10pro-how-can-i-change-a-label-image/60341981#60341981)

Comment: thanks for the response, I looked at your code and I'm not quite sure how to apply the theory here as you are using images where I am using fill color of canvas widgets.